# Can you loop through commands with a list of files in Tox

Tags: python, tox

In my tox.ini file for a python project I am working on I have a formatting step like so:

```
[testenv:formatting]
    deps =
    isort
    black
    flake8
    flake8-quotes
    pep8-naming
commands =
    # Check source code
    isort {toxinidir}/project --check-only  --recursive
    black {toxinidir}/project --check --diff  --py36
    flake8 {toxinidir}/project

    # Check tests
    isort {toxinidir}/tests --check-only  --recursive
    black {toxinidir}/tests --check --diff  --py36
    flake8 {toxinidir}/tests

    # Check setup.py
    isort {toxinidir}/setup.py --check-only  --recursive
    black {toxinidir}/setup.py --check --diff  --py36
    flake8 {toxinidir}/setup.py

    # Check docs/conf.py
    isort {toxinidir}/docs/conf.py --check-only  --recursive
    black {toxinidir}/docs/conf.py --check --diff  --py36
    flake8 {toxinidir}/docs/conf.py
```

Is there some way to remove the verbosity of this and run those 3 commands (`isort`, `black`, and `flake8`) on a list of files instead?

Something like:

```
commands =
    isort {toxinidir}/{list_of_files} --check-only --recursive
    black {toxinidir}/{list_of_files} --check --diff  --py36
    flake8 {toxinidir}/{list_of_files}
```

where `{list_of_files}` is something like `["project", "tests", "setup.py", "docs/conf.py"]`?

I've tried doing a shell for loop but that doesn't seem to work in the commands.

Is there something I'm missing here or is this just not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used `isort` and `black`, but I'd expect all three of those commands to accept multiple arguments at once, so you should be able to write:

```
isort {toxinidir}/project {toxinidir}/tests {toxinidir}/setup.py {toxinidir}/docs/conf.py --check-only  --recursive
black {toxinidir}/project  {toxinidir}/tests {toxinidir}/setup.py {toxinidir}/docs/conf.py --check --diff  --py36
flake8 {toxinidir}/project {toxinidir}/tests {toxinidir}/setup.py {toxinidir}/docs/conf.py
```

PS: By default, `tox` runs commands with `{toxinidir}` as the current directory, so you can leave that part off for brevity:

```
isort project tests setup.py docs/conf.py --check-only  --recursive
# etc.
```

Comment: You are correct, this does seem to work. I suppose it doesn't quite address the question on whether you can do any sort of looping or automation which I initially was trying to do, but it definitely solves my immediate problem. Thanks!